# reformat output of hierarchical data, based on an element

Tags: json, jq, hierarchical-data

Given the following json, which contains hierarchical data, i need to convert the following flat structure into a parent child json output format:

```
[{
    "ID": 1042,
    "NameID": "200",
    "Name": "related",
    "path": "1042"
}, {
    "ID": 1561,
    "NameID": "  230",
    "Name": "Patr",
    "FatherID": 1042,
    "path": "1042\/1561"
}, {
    "ID": 1370,
    "NameID": "    230",
    "Name": "Dog",
    "FatherID": 1561,
    "path": "1042\/1561\/1370"
}, {
    "ID": 1560,
    "NameID": "    230.1",
    "Name": "Ort",
    "FatherID": 1561,
    "path": "1042\/1561\/1560"
}, {
    "ID": 213,
    "NameID": "    232",
    "Name": "Jim",
    "FatherID": 1561,
    "path": "1042\/1561\/213"
}]
```

How i could get an output like below, based on the path hierarchy?:

i have replaced the first values only, since i need to show that the depth may go on and on...

```
[
  {
    "200": "related",
    "Children": [
      {
        "  230": "Patr",
        "Children": [
          {
            "230.1": "Ort",
            "Children": [
              {
                "NameID": "Name",
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "NameID": "Name",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "NameID": "Name"
                      },
                      {
                        "NameID": "Name"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "NameID": "Name",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "NameID": "Name"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the following solution is to convert the flat array into a hierarchical structure.  We use `setpath` to do this as follows:

```
reduce .[] as $element ({};
  setpath($element | .path | split("\/");
          $element | {NameID, Name}))
```

With your input, this produces the following:

```
{
  "1042": {
    "NameID": "200",
    "Name": "related",
    "1561": {
      "NameID": "  230",
      "Name": "Patr",
      "1370": {
        "NameID": "    230",
        "Name": "Dog"
      },
      "1560": {
        "NameID": "    230.1",
        "Name": "Ort"
      },
      "213": {
        "NameID": "    232",
        "Name": "Jim"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now it's just a question of munging, which can be done using the following helper function:

```
def promote:
  . as $in
  | (if .NameID then {(.NameID): .Name } else {} end) as $base
  | del(.NameID) | del(.Name)
  | if length == 0 then $base
    else $base + {Children: (reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k ([]; . + [$in[$k] | promote] ))}
    end;
```

With this def, the solution becomes:

```
reduce .[] as $element ({};
  setpath($element | .path | split("\/");
          $element | {NameID, Name}))
| promote
| .Children
```

### Output

```
[
  {
    "200": "related",
    "Children": [
      {
        "  230": "Patr",
        "Children": [
          {
            "    230": "Dog"
          },
          {
            "    230.1": "Ort"
          },
          {
            "    232": "Jim"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: how the above should be altered if we wanted a json hash as output?

Comment: Hash on what? Hierarchical or flat?  Maybe you should ask a new SO Q, following the [mcve] guidelines?

Comment: So you want a flat hash?  What are its keys supposed to be?

Comment: [
  {
    "200": "related",
    "Children": [
      {
        "  230": "Patr",
        "Children": [
          {
            "    230": "Dog"
          },
          {
            "    230.1": "Ort"
          },
          {
            "    232": "Jim"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
] how this json could be transformed using hashes instead of arrays? output json would be nice if it could have  kept the key value pairs like: "NameID": "230.1",
        "Name": "Ort"

Comment: Please ask a new question following the [mcve] guidelines.